# How to call destructor of type in template?

Tags: c++, templates, constructor, destructor, template-function

For example, we have a function like that:

```
template <typename TYPE>
void construct_and_destruct(TYPE & object)
{
    //...
}
```

We **cant** call constructor and destructor like `object.Type()` and `object.~Type()` (no true now) ( Whyy? **=C** )

To call the constructor we can like `new(&object) TYPE()`. And I dont know how to call destructor (no exist placement `delete`). How to do this?

Comment: You should split the code you're interested from the dtor and into a separate member function and call that instead.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can call the destructor as:

```
object.~TYPE();
```

but it's likely not what you want, and are subject to a double delete.

The constructor is as simple as:

```
object = TYPE();
```

Comment: You're right, but `object = TYPE();` perform additional `operator =`. Instead this better use placement new (with strange syntax **=)**).

Comment: @4Bytes: No. Just don't do `object.~TYPE(); new (object) TYPE();` It's much cleaner to use `object = TYPE();` Let the system clean up after itself.

Comment: @David This is incorrect: You are doing an assignment. `TYPE` must assume in its assignment operator that one of its constructors previously has been called. You will be violating that.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb - I'm assuming that 4Bytes wants to "reset" an object originally declared as `TYPE object` to some primeval state, and is doing so via `new (&object) TYPE(<some argument list>);`.  There's a problem with just using placement new here: That placement new can cause resources allocated in `object` to leak. Solution: Destruct `object` before reconstructing it. This is why I think h4Bytes is asking about explicitly calling the destructor. There's a much better way to accomplish what he wants besides this convoluted call to the destructor followed by placement new.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb - I made an error in my comment from five hours ago when I wrote `new (object) TYPE()`. That's illegal of course; the argument to placement new is supposed to be a pointer. What I meant was `new (&object) TYPE()` -- or perhaps something other than the default constructor.

Comment: have to agree with Luchian.. if you're passing in a  TYPE &object,   then its almost certainly already been constructed by the caller,  so don't use a placement new on it...    If the function took raw memory as an argument,   then its more likely to need a placement new on it.

Answer (score 3):

I came at this with a slightly different problem, but also for placement-new/delete, and the solution should be similar.

Given a dependent type name the placement new:

```
new (&foo) typename AT::T(arg, arg, arg);
```

The associated delete is tricky:

```
foo.~ typename AT::T();  // Doesn't work, nor do variations of syntax
```

The modern solution seems to be `std::destroy_at(&foo)` but my compiler doesnt have full C++17. Rolling a basic version of your own isn't difficult however:

```cpp
template <typename T>
constexpr void destroy_at(T* p)
{
  p->~T();
}
```

Seems fine.

Answer (score 1):

`object.~TYPE()` and `object.~TYPE::TYPE()` are both correct I think. Sounds a bit dubious however, what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Nope, `object.~TYPE()` is incorrect. I know that construct_and_destruct is useless function, but I write this for **example**.

Comment: `object.~TYPE()` is correct. That said, why would you want to call the destructor?

Comment: @David Hammen, sorry, I was wrong. Destructor work as well. It's required to perform my tasks.

Comment: @DavidHammen If you had a union type, with some variable for descriminating which type it is, you would need to call the right destructor in your own destructor.

Comment: @DavidHammen: Also, if you allocated with a custom `new` operator, you cannot call the standard `delete` but you need to call your own.

Answer (score 1):

Try this [Calling destructor with decltype and\or std::remove_reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17328454/calling-destructor-with-decltype-and-or-stdremove-reference), it worked for me to call the destructor of an unqualified type (unspecified inner class inside a template argument)...