# Calling destructor with decltype and\or std::remove_reference

Tags: c++, c++11, std, destructor, decltype

Is it possible to call destructor(without operator delete) using decltype and\or std::remove_reference? Here's an example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

using namespace std;

class Test
{
    public:
    Test() {}
    virtual ~Test() {}
};

int main()
{
    Test *ptr;

    ptr->~Test(); // works
    ptr->~decltype(*ptr)(); // doesn't work
    ptr->~std::remove_reference<decltype(*ptr)>::type(); // doesn't work

return 0;
}
```

Comment: No, it is not possible.

Comment: A destructor is not a type.

Comment: ... but you could use a function template to explicitly call the dtor (deducing the type). Not sure what you'd gain, though.

Comment: DyP, template is a possible solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use an alias template to get an unqualified type name when all you have is a qualified type name. The following should work

```
template<typename T> using alias = T;
ptr->~alias<std::remove_reference<decltype(*ptr)>::type>();
```

Note that if the `remove_reference` thing worked, it would still be dangerous, because by the qualified type name, you would inhibit an virtual destructor call. By using the alias template, virtual destructors still work.

Note that GCC4.8 appears to accept

```
ptr->std::remove_reference<decltype(*ptr)>::type::~type();
```

Clang rejects this. I have long given up trying to understand how destructor name lookup works (if you look into the clang source, you will note that the clang developers also do not follow the spec, because they say that it makes no sense here). There exist DRs that cover destructor call syntax and how they are messed up. Therefor, I would recommend not using any complicated syntax here.

Comment: Are you sure that decltype-specifiers are not allowed? e.g. [expr.prim.general]/8 "A class-name or decltype-specifier prefixed by ~ denotes a destructor"

Comment: @DyP I think I did not state that decltype-specifiers are not allowed. But that's irrelevant, since the `decltype` specifier will denote a reference type and therefor cannot be used in his example.

Comment: Could you explain it more, please? I didn't understand case when virtual destructor will not be called.

Comment: @user1266334 i recommend opening a different question for that.

Answer (score 1):

In case if your compiler does not support template using command you can do the following:

**Define the template struct:**

```
template<class T> struct unwind_alias { static VOID destroy(T* ptr) { ptr->~T(); }; };
```

**Use it to destroy the object**

```
unwind_alias<std::remove_reference<decltype(*ptr)>::type>::destroy(ptr);
```

Hope it will help anyone.

Answer (score 1):

With C++17, you can also just use [`std::destroy_at`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/destroy_at).