# Explicit destructor call with an alias template and inheritance

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, inheritance, destructor

Inspired by the question and its answer [Calling destructor with decltype and\or std::remove_reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17328454/calling-destructor-with-decltype-and-or-stdremove-reference/), I have been trying to do the same in my code. Unfortunately, the following MWE

```
template<class T>
using alias = T;

class Yo {
    public:
        ~Yo() { }
};

template<class A>
class Lo {
    protected:
        A a;
};

template<class A>
class Foobar : public Lo<A> {
    public:
        typedef Lo<A> super;
        inline void expl() {
                super::a.~alias<decltype(super::a)>();
        }
};

int main() {
    Foobar<Yo> A;
    A.expl();
}
```

compiles fine with g++, but with clang I get

> mwe.cpp:20:27: error: 'alias' following the 'template' keyword
>   does not refer to a template

And with icpc, I get

> mwe.cpp(20): internal error: bad pointer

I'm not sure if this is correct C++, or if this is a bug inside the compilers. Do you see a workaround ?

Comment: to me it looks that `alias` should be defined in the `Yo` class, otherwise it won't be found, since it's not a member of the scope that name is looked up in (the class itself and its base classes)

Comment: This compiles with `clang`, but not with `g++` anymore.

Comment: Is this a situation where the `template` keyword could be used for disambiguation? Admittedly, I can't see how that would work.

Comment: @PiotrS. The pseudo-destructor-name here is `alias<..>()`. Arguably, this name doesn't contain a nested-name-specifier, hence [basic.lookup.qual]p6 doesn't apply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a way to make it works. But to do so I Had to make the variable a in Lo class public

```
 template<class T>
 using alias = T;

class Yo {

public:
    ~Yo() { }
};

template<class A>
class Lo {
public:
    A a;
};

template<class A>
class Foobar : public Lo<A> {
public:
    typedef Lo<A> super;

    using type = alias<decltype(super::a)>;

    inline void expl() {
            super::a.~type();
    }
};

int main() {
   Foobar<Yo> A;
   A.expl();
}
```

EDIT i just thought about something

At Foobar class you get a template Parameters A which will be passed to the super class Lo. So the variable a has the type you get in your template !
So you can simply do :

```
using type = alias<A>;

inline void expl() {
        super::a.~type();
}
```

Now you can have a protected variable a [link](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8cf57406e2eeb722)

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately I cannot do this change in my complete application.

Comment: Please tell me if my assertion about the type of the variable will always valid in your application

Comment: Thanks, this workaround fits into my application. Now I'm still wondering if the initial code is valid C++.