# C++: Explicitly call destructor of template parameter's typedef

Tags: c++, destructor, typedef

I have the following:

```
template <typename X> struct A {
    typedef X _X;
};

template <typename Y> struct B { // Y is struct A
    typename Y::_X x;
    void call_destructor () {
        x.~Y::_X(); // This doesn't work
        x.Y::~_X(); // This as well
    }
};
```

which doesn't compile, saying that

> qualified type does not match destructor name

Using the keyword `typename` before the call also does not work. However, the following does compile:

```
template <typename Y> struct B {
    typename Y::_X x;
    typedef typename Y::_X __X;
    void call_destructor () {
        x.~__X(); // This works
    }
};
```

Can someone explain to me why, and is there any way to make do without the `typedef`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
x.~Y::_X(); // This doesn't work
```

Is a syntax error, I believe the compiler parses it as calling `_X` in `~Y`

In the second case, when you call a destructor<sup>†</sup> containing `::`, the last two type names must denote the same type

```
s.A::~B();
```

where `A` and `B` must be the same type. `A` and `B` are both looked up in the scope specified by previous specifiers, if any

```
x._X::~_X();     // error, can't find _X in current scope
```

The logical fix would be

```
x.Y::_X::~_X();           // error, _X is dependent name
x.typename Y::_X::~_X();  // error, typename cannot be here
```

Since `Y::_X` is a [dependent name](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/dependent_name#The_typename_disambiguator_for_dependent_names), `typename` is required to disambiguate it as a type, but the grammar of destructors doesn't admit a `typename` within the expression. The end result is you must use a type alias

```
using X = typename Y::_X;
x.~X();
```

On the other hand the easiest way to write-and-forget a destructor call is simply

```
x.~decltype(x)();
```

but gcc and msvc fails to compile this.

<sub>† More precisely, a pseudo-destructor call</sub>

Comment: Shouldn't [\[temp.res\]/4](http://www.eel.is/c++draft/temp.res#4.sentence-2) apply?

Comment: @xskxzr The grammar production rules require `nested-name-specifier` to be exactly `type-name ::` which rules that out. Or so I think.

Answer (score 5):

You should call the destructor differently using

```
x.Y::_X::~_X()
```

The following compile fine for me:

```
template <typename X> struct A {
    typedef X _X;
};

template <typename Y> struct B { // Y is struct A
    typename Y::_X x;
    void call_destructor () {
       x.Y::_X::~_X(); // This as well
    }
}; 


int main(){
  B<A<int> > b;
  b.call_destructor();
}
```

Comment: The funny thing is that this doesn't work on Clang though. I wonder if that's a bug or whether there's some obscure rule why it's ill formed.

Comment: Indeed, I only tried it with gcc at first. This is a mystery to me.

Answer (score 0):

Using this method https://stackoverflow.com/a/17328828/15006896 I was able to call the destructors for each object in an allocated array containing unspecified dependent types inside a template function.

ie:

```
template <typename CompoundType>
void process_data()
{
    const size_t MAX_SIZE = some_value;
    CompoundType* obj_list = new CompoundType[MAX_SIZE];

    // Receive data into obj_list and process it...

    CompoundType* p_record = records;
    for (int i = 0; i < MAX_SIZE; i++)
    {
        // Below is the magic to call the destructors!
        p_record->std::remove_reference<decltype(*p_record)>::type::~type();
        p_record++;
    }

    delete[] obj_list;
}
```

NB: The above template function was called with the following specialisations, with each inner class dynamically allocating memory:

```
process_data<A::One>();
process_data<B::Two>();
process_data<C::Three>();
```

ie: the name of the inner class is not known inside the template function, and simply trying to call ~CompoundType doesn't work at all.