# Formally correct way to explicitly call destructor of typedef'd class type

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, destructor, typedef, scope-resolution

This question is related to: [C++: Explicitly call destructor of template parameter's typedef](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45873952/c-explicitly-call-destructor-of-template-parameters-typedef)

I have the following:

```
class A {
public:
  typedef std::shared_ptr<A> Ptr;
  …
};
```

Later on, I have a variable `ptr` of type `A::Ptr *` obtained via placement new, essentially by a call to a function like this:

```
A::Ptr * f(A::Ptr obj) {
  void * placement = get_legacy_storage(sizeof(obj));
  return new(placement) A::Ptr(obj);
}
```

I now want to undo the placement-new with an explicit destructor call. I do it like this:

```
ptr->A::Ptr::~Ptr();
```

As remarked in a comment to an answer to the linked question, this works on gcc, but not with clang. § 12.4p13 of the standard says

> In an explicit destructor call, the destructor name appears as a  ~ followed by a *type-name* or *decltype-specifier* that denotes the destructor's class type.

but I'm unsure how this interacts with typedefs and scope resolution.
So, my questions are:

1. What are the C++-11 standards-compliant ways of explicitly calling the destructor in the above situation (ideally without revealing the type of `Ptr`)?
2. Do the answers for 1 work in gcc and/or clang? If not, what are the generally accepted workarounds?

Comment: You're going to have to show how you initialised `ptr` using placement `new`.   As you've worded it, you could have done that in various ways, and the technique to "undo" the effect will depend on how it was done.

Comment: @Peter I edited the question

Comment: It's not very satisfying from a language lawyer perspective, but `using T = A::Ptr; ptr->~T();` is accepted by both.

Comment: Just reread everything concerning destructors, the current revision of the answer in the linked post holds for C++17, but not C++11. In C++11 the grammar is ambiguous (or so I think), and that is probably why it was changed. `ptr->A::Ptr::~Ptr();` is correct, but clang rejects it and the workaround as chris mentioned is to alias the type.

Comment: Nope, it's [cwg #1753](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#1753), which is unrelated, but does change things.

Answer (score 0):

With the minimized example

```
struct A {};
struct B {
    using T = A;
};
int main() {
    A* a = new A;
    a->B::T::~T();
}
```

Godbolt indicates that Clang accepts the code as of version 11.

I'm not totally sure why Clang didn't accept this before, but perhaps it was related to a syntactic ambiguity which is discussed in more detail [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74341695/481267).

The ambiguity is between

*postfix-expression* `.` `template`<sub>opt</sub> *id-expression*

and

*postfix-expression* `.` *pseudo-destructor-name*

This ambiguity was resolved by [P1131R2](https://wg21.link/P1131R2), and the resolution was voted as a DR; see [CWG 2292](https://wg21.link/CWG2292). So I think that, even in C++11, the code should be considered valid.