# How are ambiguous grammar resolved?

Tags: c++, c++14, language-lawyer

Is there a general rule on how to resolve ambiguous grammar?

In particular, a [*pseudo-destructor-name*](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4140/expr.post#nt:pseudo-destructor-name) includes these production rules

> nested-name-specifier<sub>opt</sub> type-name :: ~ type-name
>
> nested-name-specifier<sub>opt</sub> ~ type-name

And [*nested-name-specifier*](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4140/expr.prim.general#nt:nested-name-specifier) includes

> nested-name-specifier identifier ::
>
> type-name ::

Given the following

```
struct A
{
    struct B {};
    B b;
};

A a;
a.b.A::B::~B();
```

Which of the following production is choosed for the last line?

> type-name :: type-name :: ~ type-name
>
> type-name :: identifier :: ~ type-name

This has significance in a templated context, since [[temp.res]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4140/temp.res#5)

> In a nested-name-specifier that immediately contains a nested-name-specifier that depends on a template parameter, the identifier or simple-template-id is implicitly assumed to name a type, without the use of the typename keyword.

Comment: Wait a second, where did `A` come from in this `a.b.A::B::~B();` expression?

Comment: @bartop Exactly what I was wondering. How would class member b have a "A" member?

Comment: The name of the destructor for `a.b` is `A::B::~B`. This is an explicit destructor call.

Comment: In case of ambiguity for type names for templates, I thought that to refer to the type name needs to have been marked with `typename` to disambiguate.

Comment: I'm wondering whether this truly matters. The implicit `typename` is for constructs like `A::B<T>::C::~C`. You don't need to write`A::typename B<T>::C::~C`. But neither `B<T>` nor `typename B<T>` can be parsed as an `identifier`. That leaves just `type-name`, resolving the ambiguity.

Comment: @MSalters Given a template parameter `T`, a variable `x` of type `T::X` you might write `x.T::X::~X();`. This is arguably not much an issue because one of the production rule for pseudo-destructor-name got removed in C++17 but for a completely different reason.

Comment: @PasserBy: Fair point. Of course the second `X` makes it clear that `X` is a type-name, but that's now how the parser works.

Comment: I believe for your example the grammar `postfix-expression . template_opt id-expression` should be chosen, but I cannot find the rule to resolve this ambiguity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where grammatical ambiguities occur, they should be accompanied by a disambiguation rule. Some such rules are fairly specific (*e.g.* [expr.unary.op]/10) while others are quite general (*e.g.* [dcl.ambig.res]/1). If there is no disambiguation rule that applies to a given ambiguity, the ambiguity represents an unintended defect in the standard. There is no disambiguation rule that is general enough to resolve all conceivable ambiguities.

---

In the C++14 grammar, there is an ambiguity you didn't mention (pointed out by @xskxzr); it's between

*postfix-expression* `.` `template`<sub>opt</sub> *id-expression*

and

*postfix-expression* `.` *pseudo-destructor-name*

(see [expr.post]/1).

Since `A::B` is actually a *class* type, presumably this ambiguity is intended to be resolved in favour of the former. In fact, if it were interpreted as a *pseudo-destructor-name*, it would be ill-formed under [expr.pseudo]/2. The reason why it's called a *pseudo*-destructor call is that it operates on scalar types, which do not have actual *destructors*:

> The left-hand side of the dot operator shall be of scalar type. [..] This scalar type is the object type. The cv-unqualified versions of the object
> type and of the type designated by the *pseudo-destructor-name* shall be the same type. [...]

There does not seem to be an applicable disambiguation rule, so this could be viewed as a defect. However, in C++20, the grammar was changed anyway, so it's moot. I will discuss this more later in the answer.

---

Suppose we change your example so that it involves a scalar type:

```
struct A
{
    using C = int;
    C c;
};

A a;
a.c.A::C::~C();
```

Now, `A::C::~C` cannot be an *id-expression* because if it were an *id-expression*, it would have to be a *qualified-id* ([expr.prim.general]/9) consisting of a *nested-name-specifier* `A::C::` and an *unqualified-id* `~C`, and `~C` can only be an *unqualified-id* if `C` is either a *class-name* or a *decltype-specifier* ([expr.prim.general]/1), but `C` is not a *class-name* because it has not been declared as a class ([class]/1). So `A::C::~C` can only be a *pseudo-destructor-name*, not an *id-expression*.

So now the question becomes how to interpret `A::C::~C` as a *pseudo-destructor-name*. This illustrates the ambiguity that you intended to illustrate.

The submitter of [CWG 1753](https://wg21.link/cwg1753) seemed to think that the *nested-name-specifier* `~` *type-name* form is only intended to cover the case where the *nested-name-specifier* designates a namespace (not a class). The issue page indicates that this issue was voted as a DR. That means that its resolution—which was to remove the *nested-name-specifier* `~` *type-name* production—is retroactive. In other words, the committee officially eliminated this ambiguity, not by inserting an ambiguity resolution rule, but by saying that the *nested-name-specifier* `~` *type-name* interpretation never should have been legal in the first place.

**So the correct interpretation is *nested-name-specifier* *type-name* `::` `~` *type-name*.**

---

In C++20, the concept of a *pseudo-destructor-name* was abolished altogether. This means that the ambiguity mentioned by @xskxzr was also fixed. In C++20, what used to be a *pseudo-destructor-name* is now just a special type of *id-expression* that occurs when the destructor that it denotes is a fake destructor (*i.e.* one of a non-class type). (For the curious, this change was made by [P1131R2](https://wg21.link/P1131R2).)